# Which is right, "welcome party" or "welcoming party"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

or is it okay with both?
someone said it's awkward to use former one, but i just want to know how native speakers feel when they hear each.

Comment: A "welcome party" is a party that you are pleased has occurred and that you hoped for in advance. A "welcoming party" is a party (group of people) whose purpose is to welcome some other person.

Comment: I'm glad that you want to participate, but questions like this require context. You should add more context to your question to make it answerable.   Plus, since this a grammar website, proper capitalization would be appreciated.  The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) contains a lot of good advice.

Answer (score 2):

I found that somebody asked the exact question many years before, on two different forums:

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/164850-welcome-party-or-welcoming-party

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/welcome-party-or-welcoming-party.2321769/

The answers on both pages are in agreement. Interestingly, both terms are appropriate in their own context, but do not mean the same thing:

> Stick with "welcome party" if you are talking about a celebration (with food and drinks). A "welcoming party" would be a group of people gathered to meet someone -- user @boozer on [forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/welcome-party-or-welcoming-party.2321769/)
>
> To my ear a welcome party is an event and a welcoming party is a group of people (with the task of welcoming someone) -- user @BobK on [www.usingenglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/164850-welcome-party-or-welcoming-party)

Your question does not specify which meaning you have in mind. You might edit to clarify. May I add that a group of people assembled to welcome somebody is also called ["welcoming committee"](https://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/welcoming_committee.htm) or ["reception committee"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reception_committee) but "welcoming committee" can also *possibly* mean "a committee that is friendly and welcoming" so "reception committee" might be a better choice than both "welcoming party" and "welcoming committee" to avoid confusing the listener or reader.

Note: the source of confusion is the word "party", which could refer to an event or a group of people.

Comment: Nicely done, +1. You might want to note that the source of confusion is the word "party", which could refer to an event or a group of people.